# How hide a row on button click in ios7/uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi am new in iOS development.

I have a `UITableViewController` having 4 sections and one row in each section.
In section 1, I have a hide button that should hide the row in section 1.
When I click this button again, then row should re-appear.

I am using following code:

```
-(void)hide:(id)sender
{
    HideBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    isReadMoreButtonTouched = YES;

    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
    [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: HideBtn.tag
                                                                   inSection:0]]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

---

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        if(isReadMoreButtonTouched && [indexPath row] == indexOfReadMoreButton) {
            //design your read more label here
            CGRect detailFrame = [Utility getlabelHeight:CGRectMake(10,0,310,20)
                                            withFontName:appFont
                                             andFontSize:15
                                                 andText:description];
            DeatilsTxtView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:detailFrame];
            DeatilsTxtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            DeatilsTxtView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:appFont size:15];
            DeatilsTxtView.text = description;
            [DeatilsTxtView setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            DeatilsTxtView.numberOfLines = 0;
            [DeatilsTxtView sizeToFit];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:DeatilsTxtView];
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && isReadMoreButtonTouched && [indexPath row] == indexOfReadMoreButton) {
        float height = 10;
        description = [description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        CGRect frame1 = [Utility getlabelHeight:CGRectMake(0,10, 250,20)
                                   withFontName:appFont
                                    andFontSize:15
                                        andText:description];
        height = height+frame1.size.height;
        return height;
    }
}
```

Using this code, when I run that time row invisible and when i click hide button row visible **but** when I again click its not invisible.

I want when I click hide button that time row should invisible and when i again click, row should become visible.

Comment: try to make height of that row to zero in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hiding before you are not making isReadMoreButtonTouched flag **FALSE** and also not providing any step for FALSE in cellForRowAtIndex method. Check out below lines to be added.

```
-(void)hide:(id)sender
{
  HideBtn = (UIButton *)sender;

  If(!isReadMoreButtonTouched);
    isReadMoreButtonTouched = YES;
  else
    isReadMoreButtonTouched = N0; /* Making isReadMoreButtonTouched FALSE for making row invisible on second tap of button */

  [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
  [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: HideBtn.tag  inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
  [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

Also in cellForRowAtIndex method-

```
if(isReadMoreButtonTouched && [indexPath row]== indexOfReadMoreButton)
{
    // design your read more label here
//Detail TextView
[cell.contentView addSubview:DeatilsTxtView];
}
else     /* ADD THIS ELSE PART SO AS TO REMOVE SUBVIEW ADDED */
{
  [cell.contentView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Similarly you will provide false condition in heightForRowAtIndexPath method as per you need.

If any query let me know.

Comment: If(!isReadMoreButtonTouched);
    isReadMoreButtonTouched = YES;
  else
    isReadMoreButtonTouched = N0;  in this line having error implicit declarion 'if' function c99 err0r

Comment: your welcome..also you could vote up and choose my answer as right that would be nice :)